# Perspective shadows from semi-hexagonal shapes (like flags)

Tags: html, css, material-design, shadow, perspective

The targeted design looks like this:

[image: a busy cat]

My markup and CSS can be seen in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n2bynh57/

HTML:

```
<div id="steps">
                <ol class="para-small-color">
                    <span class="wedge"></span>
                    <li>
                        <div class="counter">1</div>
                        <div class="list-elem">
                        </div>
                    </li>   
                    <li>
                        <div class="counter">2</div>
                        <div class="list-elem">
                        </div>
                    </li>                   
                    <span class="wedge"></span>
                    <li>
                        <div class="counter">3</div>
                        <div class="list-elem">
                        </div>
                    </li>                   
                    <li>
                        <div class="counter">4</div>
                        <div class="list-elem">
                        </div>
                    </li>                   
                </ol>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#steps ol, #steps ul{
    -padding-start: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}
#steps ol>li:nth-child(2), #steps ol>li:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
#steps ol>li:nth-child(3), #steps ol>li:nth-child(6) {
    margin-left: 5.6rem;
}
#steps ol>li, #steps ol>li ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
#steps ol>li{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 1.4rem;
}

.list-elem{
    margin-left: 2rem;
}
.counter{
    font: 400 4rem Arial;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    color: #a83443;
}
.wedge {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 25px 8px 0;
    border-color: transparent #b0b0b0 transparent transparent;
}
#steps ol li:nth-of-type(1)>.counter, #steps ol li:nth-of-type(3)>.counter {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #E9E9E9;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#steps ol li:nth-of-type(1)>.counter:after, #steps ol li:nth-of-type(3)>.counter:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid #E9E9E9;
}
```

I managed to get the semi-hexagonal shapes right and the corner flat shadow. But I'm not sure how the perspective flat shadows could be made. Using `box-shadow` doesn't seem to work right, because it cannot achieve the wedge-shaped perspective shadows. So, I suppose it might work with some border properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. This is possible to achieve by creating the same elements again and placing the clones underneath them using z-indexed layers, then applying some transformations on these shadow-coloured shapes to make them look as if they are perspective shadows.

I will edit this post later to add the solution for reference, once I finish writing the code.

**Solution**: http://codepen.io/ciprianf/pen/epvvep